# how to assign the html value to the php variable without post or get method

Tags: php, javascript

in my program i had a php value $test = 2 using this value i done some operation 
for example: in my page i had a 2 block A and B and one select box. If the test value is A it enable the div A, if the value is B it hide div A and also i am able to show and hide the div using the select box onchange event. please check my sample code given below

```
$test = $_GET["id"];

<select name="hideme" id="hideme" onchange="enableme();">
<option value="A">Show</option>
<option value="B">Hide</option>
</select>

if($test == 'A') {
<div id="div1" name="div1">
xxxxxxxxxxxxx
</div>
}
```

Js Function :

```
function enableme() {
if(document.getElementByID('hideme').value == "A") {
document.getElementById.style.display ="block";

} else {

document.getElementById.style.display ="none";

}
}
```

my issue is at fist time using the $test($_get) value it show the correct div but the on change event is not working because of , if condition. If i remove the if condition then it show div A even if the value of the $test is B. how could i handle both. Please Help me

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `document.getElementById('div1').style.display ="block";` in your JS block?

Comment: Your code looks pretty mangled, you might want to tidy that up.

Comment: yes, is there is any other way to change the if condition variable because i think due the if condition only the div style  not changing

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your JS function be something like:

```
function enableme() {
    if(document.getElementByID('hideme').value == "A") {
        if (document.getElementById('div1'))
            document.getElementById('div1').style.display = "block";
    } else {
        if (document.getElementById('div1'))
            document.getElementById('div1').style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: yes you are correct but the problem is as per the js function the value is 'A' so it change the style into block or none.But the  $_get value still same so the if condition does not  allow to change the div style

Comment: I think you are confused about what runs in the browser and what runs on the server.